# Calculate multiple range slider value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to calculate price from 3 range slider, however it's return wrong result, what I tried so far:

```js
let result1 = 0;
let result2 = 0;
let result3 = 0;

$('input[name="cdnvideolive"]').change(function() {
  let val = parseInt($(this).val());
  let price = 1000;
  let result1 = price * val;
  $('var').text(result1 + result2 + result3);
});

$('input[name="cdnvideovid"]').change(function() {
  let val = parseInt($(this).val());
  let price = 2000;
  let result2 = price * val;
  $('var').text(result1 + result2 + result3);
});

$('input[name="cdnvideostor"]').change(function() {
  let val = parseInt($(this).val());
  let price = 3000;
  let result3 = price * val;
  $('var').text(result1 + result2 + result3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" name="cdnvideolive" value="1" min="1" max="50" data-steps="50">
<input type="range" name="cdnvideovid" value="1" min="1" max="20" data-steps="20">
<input type="range" name="cdnvideostor" value="1" min="1" max="30" data-steps="30">
total price: <var></var>$
```

I want total of all ranges, but it return single total. what I have done wrong?

Comment: Just remove `let` from result variables inside the change functions. You are creating new scoped variables instead of overwriting the ones on top of your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use global results and the range has to start with zero.

```js
let result1 = 0;
let result2 = 0;
let result3 = 0;

$('input[name="cdnvideolive"]').change(function() {
  let val = parseInt($(this).val());
  let price = 1000;
  result1 = price * val;
  $('var').text(result1 + result2 + result3);
});

$('input[name="cdnvideovid"]').change(function() {
  let val = parseInt($(this).val());
  let price = 2000;
  result2 = price * val;
  $('var').text(result1 + result2 + result3);
});

$('input[name="cdnvideostor"]').change(function() {
  let val = parseInt($(this).val());
  let price = 3000;
  result3 = price * val;
  $('var').text(result1 + result2 + result3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" name="cdnvideolive" value="0" min="0" max="50" data-steps="50">
<input type="range" name="cdnvideovid" value="0" min="0" max="20" data-steps="20">
<input type="range" name="cdnvideostor" value="0" min="0" max="30" data-steps="30">
total price: <var></var>$
```